# How to use Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration with Antlr4?

Tags: .net, botframework

I want to use Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration templates in my project.
I installed the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration NuGet package (version 4.16.0) but we I try to use `ParseResource`, I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr4.Runtime.Standard, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e78b2c5abd1fcb3f'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Antlr4.Runtime.Standard, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e78b2c5abd1fcb3f'
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration.TemplatesParser.InnerParseResource(LGResource resource, ImportResolverDelegate importResolver, ExpressionParser expressionParser, Dictionary`2 cachedTemplates, Stack`1 parentTemplates)
```

I tried to install Antlr4.Runtime.Standard but I can only install it with version "4.8.0". How can I get Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like installing a later version of Antlr4 worked:
`dotnet add package Antlr4.Runtime.Standard`